# How to subset a dataframe with "starts_with" function?

Tags: r

how would I subset a dataframe with "starts_with" embedded with my list of fields? Here is my attempt so far. The error requires it to be used with a selecting function, although I think I am doing just that? Thanks!

```
df <- subset(raw_df, select=c(col1, col2, col3, V1, V2, starts_with("V")))
```

Comment: Which `starts_with` function are you using? That's not a base R function. Is this from `dplyr`? Then it's odd you're not use the `dplyr::select()` verb rather than `subset`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`starts_with` is a select-helper from `tidyselect` package.  We may need `startsWith` from `base R`

```
subset(raw_df, select=c(col1, col2, col3, 
         names(raw_df)[startsWith(names(raw_df), "V")]))
```

---

Also this may be more compact in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
raw_df %>%
    select(matches('^col[1-3]$'), starts_with("V"))
```